# Does the Lorentz force change when an electric current is under a magnetic field with negative permeability?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, material-science

Most applications of the Lorentz force depend on the electric current passing by a material with positive permeability, normally ferromagnetic.
How much would change were the electric current to pass by a magnetic field displaying negative permeability and being hence diamagnetic?

Comment: Your question seems pretty unclear.  The Lorentz force acts on charges in motion—either individual pointlike charges, or macroscopic currents composed of many charges—in a region of magnetic field $\vec{B}$.  Magnetic materials are dealt with via different methods, so it's not clear what you are asking about.

Comment: The electric current is still passing by a conventional wire but is under the effect of a magnetic field with negative permeability. This is from a different material/system and not the wire itself if that is the doubt

Comment: Unlike a ferromagnet, a linear magnetic material (whether diamagnetic or paramagnetic) is not a *source* of magnetic field unless there is already another applied field.  Do you mean to ask about how the field of the wire magnetizes the material, which then in turn produces another $\vec{B}$ that acts on the current in the wire?

Comment: Correct, I am talking about the latter case, after all, an electric current will produce a corresponding magnetic field that when subjected unto a diamagnetic material will act on it.